# storing checkboxes into a list tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am fairly new to tkinter was able to get the following code.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
master = Tk()
v = IntVar()
v.set(1)
var1 = IntVar()
var2 = IntVar()
var3 = IntVar()
CategorySubmit= IntVar()
my_list = [{"Kitchen":var1},{"Electric Supply":var2},{"Books":var3}]
def get_boxes(value):
    #store the checked boxes for later use
    pass
def get_value(value):
    #print(value)
    if value=="Category":
        for widget in master.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()
        row =1
        for i in my_list:
            Checkbutton(master, text=list(i.keys())[0], variable=list(i.values())[0]).pack()
            row+=1
        Button(master, text="Submit", variable=CategorySubmit,command=get_boxes).pack()
        #save the check boxes made by user into a list then quit master
    else:
        file_chosen =filedialog.askopenfilename(title='Please Select Input File', filetypes=[('Excel files', ('.xlsx', '.csv', '.xls', 'xlsm'))])
        print(f"Done: {file_chosen}")
        master.destroy()

MODES = [
("Choice 1","ID"),
("Choice 2","Category"),
("Choice 2","Full"),
]
choice_made= StringVar()
choice_made.set('Choice 1')
for text,mode in MODES:
    Radiobutton(master,text=text,variable=choice_made,value=mode).pack()
but = Button(master,text="Submit",command=lambda: get_value(choice_made.get()))
but.pack()

master.mainloop()
print(file_chosen) #gives undefined error ?
```

I need to store the values in checkboxes into a list so I can use later. also I have an error when for the variable name outside the `master.mainloop()` , it gives `NameError: name 'file_chosen' is not defined`,

My idea is when "Choice 1" or "Choice 3" are picked a fileprompt is given so I can continue with my script later on, else if "Choice 2" 3 checkboxes that I store in a list

Comment: _"I need to store the values in checkboxes into a list so I can use later."_ - your code is already doing that. `my_list` is a list which contains references to all of the checkbutton variables.

Comment: @BryanOakley how do I know which `var` was checkboxed

Answer (score 0):

The `file_chosen` variable is local inside the `get_value()` function. To extend its scope you have to declarate as global:

```
def get_value(value):
    global file_chosen
```

Comment: how do I store the checkboxed values in a list

Comment: Can you explain better your problem? I answered only to the `NameError: name 'file_chosen' is not defined`, but I do not really understand the other one.

Comment: if you run the file the script, and choose Choice 1 or 3 , you will get the error

Comment: not if you define the `file_chosen` as global as I suggested above.

Comment: ok this solved the first issue, how can I get the value after user checkboxed

Comment: The filename is stored in variable `file_chosen`, isn't?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202890/discussion-between-hadesfv-and-0x6261627564).